# Not able to locate "sdk" in android studio and subsequently, not able to open the software

Tags: android-studio-3.1

I am new to Android and thought that android studio is the place to begin with.

I downloaded the IDE from [here](https://developer.android.com/studio/index.html#win-bundle) and installed it.
The installation is completed but, I cannot open the program. In the beginning, it said "SDK not found" and incidentally, there was no file or folder named SDK in the Android folder that I just downloaded.

Now, the software is visible in the start menu but won't open.

Comment: Go Settings > Appearance ad behavior > System settings > `Android SDK`, and download it manually

Answer (score 0):

Head to Control Panel -> Uninstall a Program, and then Uninstall Android-Studio.

Now Install Android-Studio again from setup.

This time while installing Android Studio don't cancel any download that will held in the installation process of Android-Studio!

Comment: Thank you @Dude Coder. Now I have another problem.

Comment: The second problem was about emulator not functioning due to VTx disabled. I talked to the device service provider and they helped me out with it.